# create a complex formula (glmertree) from variable names

Tags: r, model, formula

I am trying to make a formula for a mixed linear model tree (glmertree).

```
X<-data.frame(matrix(runif(100*5),100,5))
y<-rnorm(X[,1]+X[,2],1)
site<-rep(1:2,c(50,50))
X<-data.frame(y,site,X)
```

For rpart this will work

```
library(rpart)
f1<-formula(paste(names(X)[1],paste(names(X)[-c(1:2)] , 
collapse=" + "),sep=" ~ "))
rpart(f1,data=X)
```

but for glmertree, which has formula in 3 parts, it does not work.

```
lt <- lmertree(y~ 0| site | paste(names(X)[-c(1:2)],collapse=" + "),data=X)
 Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, 
  data = data,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'paste(names(X)[

lt <- lmertree(y~ 0| site | formula(paste(names(X)[-c(1:2)],collapse=" + ")),data=X)
Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
     object 'X1' not found
```

This will work

```
lt <- lmertree(y~ 0| site | X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 ,data=X)
```

however, I will have thousands of variables in the real data.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, specifying many response variables is a bit more tricky with **glmertree**, because using the dot (e.g., `y ~ 1 | site | .`) will create trouble in the iterative estimation (will try to improve this in next version of **glmertree**).

There seems to be no need to omit the intercept from the linear model in the terminal node (i.e., with `~ 0` in the formula), I would always advice to include it (otherwise, the parameter stability test probably do not test what you want them to test).

I believe your code can be simplified a bit:

```
f1 <- formula(paste("y ~ 1 | site |", paste(names(X)[-(1:2)] , collapse="+")))
lt <- lmertree(f1, data=X)
```

With 16000 predictor variables, things will become computationally heavy though. If too heavy, restricting tree size by specification of the `maxdepth` argument may help. Or the Bonferroni correction for multiple testing in the parameter stability tests may be way too conservative with so many variables, so you get no splits. Then you could specify `bonferroni = FALSE`, or set `alpha` to a value higher than the default `.05` (see also `?partykit::mob_control`).

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question.

```
f1<-formula(
   paste(names(X)[1],
                  paste("0",paste(names(X)[2]),
                      paste(names(X)[-c(1:2)] , collapse=" + "),
                        sep="|"),
                 sep=" ~ ")
           )
f1
y ~ 0 | site | X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5
lt <- lmertree(f1,data=X)
```

This works for up to about 16000 variables, then it runs into

```
Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

but that is another problem.